# java null pointer exception SQL prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have the following SQL query:

```
private static final String SQL_LIST_ALL =
    "SELECT DISTINCT * "
    + "FROM usuarios WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usuarios_grupos WHERE usuarios_grupos.id_grupo = ? AND usuarios_grupos.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario)";
```

which resides in my list() method:

```
public List<Usuarious> list() throws DAOExceptions {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Usuarious> users = new ArrayList<Usuarious>();

    try {
        connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ALL);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,groups.getId_grupo());
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            users.add(mapUser(resultSet));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOExceptions(e);
    } finally {
        close(connection, preparedStatement, resultSet);
    }

    return users;
}
```

I got a null pointer exception when I run my program. It happens here:

```
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ALL);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1,groups.getId_grupo());
```

My result set method:

```
    private static Usuarious mapUser(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Usuarious user = new Usuarious(rs.getInt("id_usuario"), rs.getString("nome"), rs.getString("setor"),
            rs.getString("senha"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("bloquear"), rs.getString("admin"));
    return user;
}
```

I am trying to pass the id_grupo into the "?" on my SQL statement. However, these methods are in my UserDAO. So, I created a new group object in the DAO to retrieve the id_grupo.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

My stack trace:

```
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @43,78 value="#{usuariousGruposBean.listOfUsuarios}": Error reading 'listOfUsuarios' on type br.view.UsuariousGruposBean
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:456)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:201)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:180)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.dao.UsuariousDAO.list(UsuariousDAO.java:93)
    at br.view.UsuariousGruposBean.getListOfUsuarios(UsuariousGruposBean.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
```

Well, I just created a Group object. It is shown here:

```
public class UsuariousDAO {


private static final String SQL_LIST_ALL =
        "SELECT DISTINCT * "
        + "FROM usuarios WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usuarios_grupos WHERE usuarios_grupos.id_grupo = ? AND usuarios_grupos.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario)";


private DAOFactory daoFactory;

Grupos groups = new Grupos();
```

Comment: On which of the two lines does nes NPE happen? I also suspect the code sample is incomplete, because `groups` is undefined.

Comment: Which of the lines gives the null pointer? Is groups not null? Can yo show the stack trace?

Comment: I get the Null pointer at these two lines:     preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ALL);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1,groups.getId_grupo()); @CodeBrickie

Comment: I created a new Group object, Grupos groups = new Grupos(). Would groups be null ?? @RogerLindsjö

Comment: So your `connection` is null? What does `daoFactory` look like?

Comment: @CodeBrickie no my connection is not null. It runs fine, if I replace the placeholder "?" with a number (my id_grupo). My daoFactory is another class that holds the connection to the database aka connectionManager

Comment: I think you should provide the complete source of `UsuariousDAO` as one coherent piece.

Answer (score 0):

Check that code 
**groups.getId_grupo()**

**groups** is an null object.
You function must have one object of type **groups** like parameter.

Comment: so I must include the following list(Grupos groups) in my parameter?