# preparedstatement with sql query referencing multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I am trying to find an example online about creating a preparedStatement that has an sql query referencing multiple tables.

For e.g. The examples I've encountered so far are always

e.g.

```
s = conn.prepareStatement ("DELETE FROM Users WHERE id_user = ?");
s.setInt (1, 2);
```

where there is only one table involved, and the method exists in the same class of the database table. E.g. User.class ,  user table in database.

The query that I have requires me to set the place holder from another table/class. In this case, my method exists in the User.class, however, it requires a the binding from a Group object.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM usuarios 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM usuarios_grupos 
 WHERE usuarios_grupos.id_grupo = ? 
 AND usuarios_grupos.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario);
```

Will the method be the following:

```
public List<Usuarious> list(Grupos groups) throws DAOExceptions {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<Usuarious> users = new ArrayList<Usuarious>();

        try {
            connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ALL);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, groups.getId_grupo());
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                users.add(mapUser(resultSet));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOExceptions(e);
        } finally {
            close(connection, preparedStatement, resultSet);
        }

        return users;
    }
```

or will it be written differently?? because I seem to be getting a NPE with this, and from the examples I've seen online. The query always reference 1 table. Is what I'm doing here wrong?

okay here is my method for groups.getId_grupo(), which exists in my Group.class:

```
public class Grupos {

Integer id_grupo;
String descricao;

public Grupos() {

}

public Grupos(Integer id_grupo, String descricao) {
    this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public Grupos(Integer id_grupo) {
    this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
}


public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public Integer getId_grupo() {
    return id_grupo;
}

public void setId_grupo(Integer id_grupo) {
    this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
}
```

}

I am calling my List list(Grupos groups) method in my ManagedBean

```
public class UsuariousGruposBean implements Serializable {

private Usuarious user = new Usuarious();
private Grupos grps = new Grupos();
private UsuariousGrupos userGroups = new UsuariousGrupos();

protected final UsuariousDAO userDAO = daoFactory.getUserDAO();
protected final GruposDAO grpDAO = daoFactory.getGruposDAO();
protected final UsuariousGruposDAO userGrpDAO = daoFactory.getUsuariousGruposDAO();

    private List<Usuarious> listOfUsuarios;
    private List<Grupos> listOfGrps;
    private List<UsuariousGrupos> listOfUserGroups;

public UsuariousGruposBean() {
    }

    public List<Usuarious> getListOfUsuarios() throws DAOExceptions {
        List<Usuarious> usuariosList = userDAO.list(grps);
        listOfUsuarios = usuariosList;
        return listOfUsuarios;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? what is the 'caused by' of the NPE?

Comment: The fact that the statement is not in a class named similarly to the table, and the fact that the statement uses several tables has no effect whatsoever with the way a prepared statement must be used. Include the stack trace of the NPE, and tell us which line in the code is causing this NPE.

Comment: at which line are you getting `NullPointerException` ?

Comment: I've checked. I am getting a NPE at preparedStatement.setInt(1, groups.getId_grupo());

Comment: Isn't this the same question as you posted earlier, but just rephrased? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355338/java-null-pointer-exception-sql-prepared-statement, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359313/setting-id-of-preparedstatement-method-that-belongs-to-object-from-another-class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210780/java-lang-nullpointerexception-jdbc and probably some more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First instance in your code can throw NPE is at:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ALL);
```

if your connection is null, your connection factory didnt return you one, check if you have a valid connection

Second place :

```
groups.getId_grupo()
```

Check if your groups is null or not

If these are not the reasons then please post your stacktrace.

Comment: I've checked, I am getting a NPE at groups.getId_grupo()

Comment: but why would I be getting a NPE at groups.getId_grupo() though?? I declared private static Grupos groups = new Grupos(); and  public static Grupos getGroups() {
        return groups;
    } in my User.class

Comment: What is getId_grupo() going to return ? an int or Integer ? Better if you could share your code

Comment: okay I will share my code. getId_grupo() is going to return an integer.

Comment: the issue here is that preparedStatement.setInt(1, null) will throw you NPE, reason being your id_grupo is null and it cannot be set, so fix is you initialize your id before setting it to the PreparedStatement

Comment: okay, so you are saying that I must assign a value to my id_grupo before setting preparedStatement.setInt (1, groups.getId_grupo())?

Comment: yep you got it right, assign a value before setting it on preparedStatement.

Comment: humm okay, here is the thing...the id for my group is assigned only I have selected a particular group from my application. Which means, I select a Group, and that id will be assigned to the method...is there anyway around this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5616/discussion-between-mprabhat-and-shaunk)

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace of your NPE should help tell you where the issue is (line #, etc.).  From what I can tell, your SQL and the way you are calling it is all valid.

Is it possible that you're receiving a null `groups` parameter, such that calling `groups.getId_grupo()` is throwing the NPE?

Comment: well, I checked, my groups parameter is null... I did the following in my User.class  public static Grupos getGroups() {
        return groups;
    } and private static Grupos groups = new Grupos(); ..but it still wouldn't work..